# CSS3 arrow hyperlink

Tags: css, hyperlink, cross-browser

Trying to make arrow link with CSS.
[This one](http://jsfiddle.net/KxKJ8/8/) works in Firefox, but has a problems in IE and webkit-based browsers with arrowhead's position. Double div used for centering link content. Any suggestions?

```
content
<a href="#" class="readmore">
    <div>
    <div>
        link content
    </div>
</div>
    </a> 
    content
```

CSS

```
.readmore {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.readmore > div {
    display: table;
    height: 30px;
    //width: 100%;
    background: #008a00;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}
.readmore > div:hover {
    background:orange;
}
.readmore > div::after {
    content:"";
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    border: 15px solid;
    margin-top:-15px;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #008a00;
    transition: border-left-color 0.2s;
}
.readmore > div::before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:6px;
    position: static;
    background:#008a00;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}
.readmore > div:hover::after {
    border-left-color:orange;
}
.readmore > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    //text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: A little bit different but take a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfozb/ (Also to be honest I haven't tried this in anything but Chrome.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `top` explicitly to `0` for the `:after` element, and also remember to set the `position:relative` for the `div` element so that the absolute positioning works as expected:

```
.readmore > div::after {
   ...
   top:0;
}

.readmore > div {
   ...
   position:relative;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KxKJ8/11/)

**NOTE**: The negative `margin-top` should be removed. The cause of your problem is you use negative `margin-top` (maybe by trial and error until it looks OK in FF), but the position also depends on the `top` and `left`. The default values of these properties are implemented differently by different browsers, the only solution to set it in order is **explicitly** set the `top`, `left` and remember the rule to determine the containing block for the absolute positioned element. (the nearest ancestor which has position as `absolute` or `relative`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code -- > 
**HTML** :

```
<div>content</div>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<div>content</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
a{
    padding:10px;
    background:#2ecc71;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
a:hover{
    background:orange;
}
a:hover:after{
   border-left: 20px solid orange;
}
a:after {
display: inline-block;
content: "";
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 20px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
border-left: 20px solid #2ecc71;
position: absolute;
right:-20px;
top:0;

}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KxKJ8/13/)

The border width and the right and top positions can be tweaked according to your needs